# Can react-router v6 routes be declared in a functional component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, authentication, react-router, react-router-dom

I have an app which is only accessible past the login, I tried implementing it this way:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';

import type Admin from '../models/admin';
import {AdminProvider} from './AdminContext';

import LoginC from './components/LoginC';
import RegisterC from './components/RegisterC';
import HomeC from './components/HomeC';

export const Server = () => {
    const [admin, setAdmin] = useState<Admin | undefined>();

    if (!admin) {
        return (
            <Routes>
                <Route path='/' element={<LoginC setAdmin={setAdmin} />} />
                <Route path='/register' element={<RegisterC setAdmin={setAdmin} />} />
            </Routes>
        );
    }

    return (
        <AdminProvider value={admin}>
            <div>Hello server my old friend!</div>
            <HomeC />
        </AdminProvider>
    );
};

export default Server;
```

The `LoginC.tsx` file has a link to the register page:

```
<Link to='/register'>Register instead</Link>
```

My intent was to return different routes when the user is logged in and when they're not.

But I get a 404 (React Router) error when I click on the "Register instead" link.

It's correctly matching the "/" route though and displaying the `LoginC` component.

Do all the routes need to be declared statically?

My intent was to return different routes depending on whether the user was set or not.

EDIT:

Here is the code creating the router:

```
import React from 'react';
import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client';

import {ThemeProvider} from '@mui/material';

import {
    createBrowserRouter as createRouter,
    RouterProvider,
} from 'react-router-dom';

import theme from './theme';
import Server from './Server';

const router = createRouter([
    {
        path: '/',
        element: <Server />,
    },
]);

const elt = document.getElementById('app');

if (!elt) {
    throw new Error('No element with id "app" found');
}

createRoot(elt).render((
    <React.StrictMode>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <RouterProvider router={router} />
        </ThemeProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>
));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `Server` is rendered on `"/"` and attempting to render descendent routes. In order for descendent routes to be matched and rendered the parent route necessarily needs to append the `"*"` wildcard matcher to its path. The `LoginC` component rendered because the path was will `"/"`, but `"/register"` was unable to be matched and render `RegisterC`.

```
const router = createRouter([
  {
    path: '/*', // <-- wildcard allows descendent route matching
    element: <Server />,
  },
]);
```

A more common route protection pattern is to use layout routes and components that check a protection condition and render an `Outlet` component or redirect to a non-protected route.

Example:

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const AdminLayout = ({ admin }) => {
  return admin
    ? (
        <AdminProvider value={admin}>
          <Outlet />
        </AdminProvider>
      )
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
};
```

```
export const Server = () => {
  const [admin, setAdmin] = useState<Admin | undefined>();

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<AdminLayout admin={admin} />}>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomeC />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path='/login' element={<LoginC setAdmin={setAdmin} />} />
      <Route path='/register' element={<RegisterC setAdmin={setAdmin} />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

And since it doesn't appear any of the RRDv6.4 Data APIs are being used, just render `Server` into a router.

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

createRoot(elt).render((
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Server />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I needed to not create the routes in `createBrowserRouter` and use `BrowserRouter` directly as such:

```
import React from 'react';
import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client';

import {ThemeProvider} from '@mui/material';

import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

import theme from './theme';
import Server from './Server';

const elt = document.getElementById('app');

if (!elt) {
    throw new Error('No element with id "app" found');
}

createRoot(elt).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Server />
            </BrowserRouter>
        </ThemeProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```